# Model composition in swagger spec without additional nesting layer

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

If I have the following example where `Settings` definition is embedded in `Thing` via composition:

```
definitions:
  Settings:
    properties: 
      foobar:
        type: number 
        format: double
      boofar:
        type: string 
  Thing:
    properties:
      allOf:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Settings'
      name:
        type: string
```

If I define a method to POST a `Thing` in editor.swagger.io, it ends up constructing JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  settings: {
    foobar: 1,
    boofar: "text here"
  },
  name: "some name"
}
```

I want to embed a model definition with composition but without the additional nested property definition -- is this possible?  This is the JSON structure I would like to have for `Thing`:

```
{
  foobar: 1,
  boofar: "text here",
  name: "some name"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your example do not really use composition as `allOf` is a property.

`allOf` is supposed to be on the root of the definition and it's an array of schema (reference or inline).

Here's the proper way to use `allOf` for your example:

swagger: '2.0'
    info:
      title: API
      version: 1.0.0

```
paths: 
  /thing:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Thing'

definitions:
  Settings:
    properties: 
      foobar:
        type: number 
        format: double
      boofar:
        type: string 
  Thing:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Settings'
      - properties:
          name:
            type: string
```

Resulting rendering in SwaggerUI:

[image]